# Flurry Event API not returning event parameter values

Tags: api, events, rest, flurry

I have been trying to use the EventMerics API to return detailed event parameter data.

I have setup a test application and have uploaded event data with parameters, I can see the data in the web interface.
However the API doesn't seem to return the parameter data as stated by the documentation.

The following call

http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=xxx&apiKey=xxx&startDate=2012-08-27&endDate=2012-08-27&eventName=heatmap%20-%20iPhone-Title-all

returns:

```
<eventMetrics type="Event" startDate="2012-08-27" eventName="heatmap - iPhone-Title-all" endDate="2012-08-27" version="1.0" generatedDate="8/27/12 10:45 PM">
<day uniqueUsers="2" totalSessions="12" totalCount="14" date="2012-08-27"/>
<parameters/>
</eventMetrics>
```

....

The parameters section is empty, I am expecting the following parameter values:

```
{touchXY : 299,465,2012-08-27 16:40:15 +0100}
{touchXY : 301,461,2012-08-27 16:29:03 +0100}
{touchXY : 192,312,2012-08-27 16:22:54 +0100}
{touchXY : 254,461,2012-08-27 16:23:04 +0100}
```

Has anyone got parameter values to return via the Flurry REST API?

Comment: Hi i m also facing the same issue. Did u get the solution for this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it? plz share the solution.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the API call used by you is correct. I would recommend you to write to support@flurry.com to investigate why this is not happening. 
(Disclaimer: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: I dropped a mail to support team regarding the same issue but didnt get the response from them. How do i receive parameters?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it? plz share the solution.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The **event name** in the request is **case sensitive** so you should check the way it's written on the site. I changed mine from "editor" to "Editor" and the problem resolved.